# Amended Tax return with ITI

Tags: united-states, amended-tax-return, itin

I did my taxes on January as single, because my wife had no ITIN. Then about 5 weeks ago, I did a amended tax return with H & R block as married with the ITIN application for my wife. It been five weeks since I did the amended tax. We received the ITIN on the four week. When can I expect my refund cheque for the amended tax return?

Answer (score 1):

You can likely expect it in the next 11 weeks, but maybe longer if they don't process the return until after the ITIN application is accepted.

Per the IRS page [Amended Return FAQ](https://www.irs.gov/filing/amended-return-frequently-asked-questions):

> **How long will it take to process an amended return?** 
>   
> A Form 1040X,
>   Amended U.S. Individual Income Tax Return can take up to 16 weeks to
>   process once we receive it.

Not always helpful, but you can check on the status of your amended return here:
https://www.irs.gov/filing/wheres-my-amended-return